# Is it necessary to create a service for login in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-services

Is it necessary to create a service for login module in angular 4? if so, why?

I am a new bee and learning angular 4. When I was going through some online tutorials, they have created services for login. Even though login is a single time functionality which can be used in only one time in a website. why to create service for this?

Thanks
Sricharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use a service, because you want to store and provide this information about the logged in user for the whole time your app runs. And that's what services are mainly for. They run your app logic (methods to process your data across the app) and store and provide data. The components are supposed to be used for the presentation only.

To sum it up:

**Yes, it's highly recommended to use a Service for the login in Angular-Apps.**

Comment: Can you please tell me what functionality the login service contains?

Comment: It contains the information whether a user is logged in (boolean via getter/setter) and the user object (object via getter/setter). You can add as much information as you want. For instance the login time and so forth...  You use the service to find out whether the login page is to be prompted and provide the information about the currently logged in user to other services that need this info.